# Netty/Grails web integration for embedded socket listener

Tags: spring, servlets, grails, netty

I am trying to embed Netty within a Grails (spring) webapp. I have all the pieces figured out and know how to use them, the only thing I dont know is which piece should I use?

The Netty app is going to be strictly for UDP and listen on port 162. Does this mean that I should set it up as a servlet? Would it be an HTTP servlet since its embedded in a webapp? Or should I just configure it as a standalone tack-on socket app that runs alongside Grails?

I know what I'm asking for is rather confusing and ambiguous, but thats because I'm just as confused myself. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Netty app is going to be strictly for UDP and listen on port 162.
>   Does this mean that I should set it up as a servlet?

Not exactly. Using a servlet means incoming requests are limited to HTTP; you need UDP.

> Or should I just configure it as a standalone tack-on socket app that
>   runs alongside Grails?

Yes, this is the correct approach. Your Netty/UDP service will run inside Grails, and Grails has a nice bootstrap feature with `servletContext` hooks for managing the service's lifecycle, important when using sockets to ensure the listening thread on the socket terminates properly.

Assuming your Netty service is something like this:

```
public MyNettyService extends Thread {
  def port

  def init(){
     ...
  }
  public void run(){
     //start listener
  }
  def shutdown(){
     ...
  }
}
```

Configure the service in `resources.groovy`:

```
   nettyService(MyNettyService){ bean ->
      bean.initMethod = "init"
      port = 12345
   }
```

In `BootStrap.groovy`, configure the service to start, and shutdown, with the container:

```
class BootStrap {

   def nettyService

   def init = { servletContext ->      
      nettyService.start()      
   }
   def destroy = {
      nettyService.shutdown()
   }
}
```

That's what I usually do, but the Grails folks here are fanatical; I'm sure someone else will show an easier way.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've tried everything I still can't get it to work :(. If someone could look at this and help me it would be great.

https://gist.github.com/diljotr/9030299

Comment: What's not working? That log file is a mile long, you need to be specific. I see the service `init` was called, that's good. What else is working? Where is it not working?

Comment: When I run-app with grails I get a single anonymous "error" that I haven't been able to track down the cause of. And the message for `Ready for connections` is called, but when I send a test packet, there is no more logging done, which indicates that the socket did not bind properly.

Furthermore: when I do `bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 162)).sync()` I don't even get the final message `Ready for connections`.

The anonymous error is thrown AFTER `new Bootstrap()`

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!! Turns out for some weird reason GNS3 lost connection to my localhost adapter. Once I restarted GNS3 I was able to receive the `Message received of type DatagramPacket` message. Thanks a lot Raffian :). I would rep you but sadly I have less than 15 rep.